# Property based testing in PHP?

Tags: php, testing, automated-tests, quickcheck, property-based-testing

In various more functional based languages there are tools (like [Quickcheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck)) which allow for [property based testing](http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/04/property-based-testing-what-is-it.html).

How would I go about property based testing in PHP?

I would like to be able to specify the in and output properties of a PHP method, and run coverage tests.

Comment: *"Quickcheck-style"* in which regards? There are of course unit testing frameworks for PHP, but which features of Quickcheck are you specifically interested in?

Comment: Deceze, I've added some more description. More info about Haskell's Quickcheck here: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck

Comment: Seriously, _how_ is this "Off Topic"?

Answer (score 17):

There are currently two libraries that offer property based testing functionality in PHP:

- [Eris](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/eris) which is a PHP port based on 
  Haskell's QuickCheck
- [PhpQuickCheck](https://github.com/steos/php-quickcheck) which is a PHP port based on clojure.test.check.

Eris has been build to work well with the PHPUnit ecosystem out-of-the-box.

PhpQuickCheck has been built to work standalone but can also be used in combination with [PhpUnit](https://phpunit.de/) and it's `@dataprovider` functionality. There is [an example of this in the repository](https://github.com/steos/php-quickcheck/blob/master/test/QCheck/QuicknDirtyTest.php).

Comment: @Kyll Thanks for the edit... looks like I forgot something there :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a go with the Faker library: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker. It won't do the testing for you, but it's great for generating the random data.

Comment: Just a note here that Faker is no longer maintained.